# Azure Active Directory - User export properties

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

can I generate an Azure AD report that includes all user informations properties such as employee IDs and employee type?

Thanks

Comment: Yup, you sure can:)

Comment: how can do it ?

Comment: yes you can.... take a look at the get-mguser cmdlet which is part of the microsoft.graph modules.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Graph API for this and $select these fields (employeeId & employeeType) in the [List Users method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Below is an example.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=employeeId,employeeType,userPrincipalName
```

I am using a Send an HTTP request action from the Office 365 Groups connector for this.

[image]